# Issues with asking if legal action have been taken?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, civil-law

I was working for a forum and have since left. To cut a long story short, I have an intrusive thought all day every day that he's going to take legal action against me, since we had a data breach(I've informed him since, he was understanding). I have little reason to believe this, other than that he may be dishonest and lie about me, but honestly it's wearing me down. So I have 2 questions:

1. May I ask him if he's taking legal action, be it criminal/civil? Is there anything wrong with this, I just want to understand my options. Moreover, does he have to be honest with his response?
2. May I ask him for an honest statement regarding my role and what my duties were whilst I worked there? Or could this be considered interfering with an investigation? Would this be impacted by the answer to number 1?

Answer (score 2):

They don't owe you a thing, and could ignore or lie to you.

To file a lawsuit against you, they must **Serve** you.  Read up on what legal service is - you probably will notice if it happens! (though things can get a little weird if you have a PMB or Registered Agent for your LLC etc - they can serve the PMB/Agent, who may fail to notify you!)

You can also check court records every week or two, to see if a case has appeared.

Now... who is your lawyer? If you have one and they know who your lawyer is, they're absolutely going to serve your lawyer; it would be negligent for them not to, and your lawyer will make them regret it.  So it could be as simple as sending  them a change of address: *Hi, I'm sending this note to everyone I've done business with in the past.  FYI, my new address is X, my phone is Y, email is Z, and my attorney is A*.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Is there anything wrong with just asking anyway? Like could I get into any legal bother?

Comment: Think about the meta-message: "Hey disgruntled customer who thinks my work was horrible and I ripped you off, **I concede that you are totally right** because I don't ever think about upgrading you or fixing my work, I only ever think about you suing me!" The customer may well say "GREAT idea, thanks for the suggestion... and the evidence!"